# search engine for word endings

Tags: regex, full-text-search

Is there a way to search the web for words that begin with any letter(s) but end in a fixed sequence? For example, I'd like a search on *otus to return lotus, POTUS, SCOTUS, Herodotus, etc.

There are plenty of tools that do this for a limited set, like a dictionary or a corpus. For example, allwords.com has an option for "words ending with". However, it searches a very small set of text. I'm looking to search the entire web.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

David

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modified word finder for language.
Since you're searching the web, this one uses Unicode.
I can make it for ascii only if needed.

The actual word is captured in *group 2*.

`(?i)([^\pL\pN]*([\pL\pN](?:[\pL\pN_-]|\pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP_-])|[?.!])*otus)(?:\pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP_-])|[?.!])*(?=[^\pL\pN]|$))`

https://regex101.com/r/HrFrEM/3

[Formatted](http://regexformat.com)

```
 (?i)
 (                             # (1 start)
      [^\pL\pN]*                    # Not letters/numbers
      (                             # (2 start), Followed by letter/number
           [\pL\pN] 
           (?:
                [\pL\pN_-]                    # Letter/number or '-'
             |  
                \pP                           # Or, punctuation if followed by punctuation/letter/number or '-'
                (?= [\pL\pN\pP_-] )
             |  
                [?.!]                         # Or, (Add) Special word ending punctuation
           )*
           otus                          # Ends with this
      )                             # (2 end)
      (?:
           \pP                           # Or, punctuation if followed by punctuation/letter/number or '-'
           (?= [\pL\pN\pP_-] )
        |  
           [?.!]                         # Or, (Add) Special word ending punctuation
      )*
      (?= [^\pL\pN] | $ )
 )                             # (1 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

You can start by creating a for loop that will do a reverse DNS on every possible IP between 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255 (you can exclude restricted ports if you like to).

Congratulations, you now have all the URLs of all websites in the world.

You can then create a for loop which will iterate through all these domains, loading the homepage and recursively loading hyperlinks.

Congratulations, you now have the entire web!

Save it to a folder (i.e. `web/`)

Then

```
cat web/* | grep otus
```

Comment: Ha! Thank you both. My apologies, but I did not fully realize how exclusively focused stackoverflow is on coding (the name should have given it away, I know). I'm not a programmer, so need an existing website tool/search engine that can do an "end of the word" search for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure why this is on hold, as my question (and f/u comment) seem pretty well defined and bounded to me. But...c'est la vie.